# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'demo.html'

Tags: python, windows

this is the code,

```
import os,stat
from os import walk

path = "C:/Users/HP/Desktop"    
owner = "DEEPTHI\HP"

for root, dirs, files in walk(path, topdown=False):  
    for f in files:  
        if os.stat(f).st_uid == owner:
            print(f)
```

after running it I receive a FileNotFoundError

Comment: what is the question? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`files` is list of just filenames under `root` as `os.walk` found them when traversing under `path`.

Now trying to access them relative to your current working directory just by their filename without rest of the path does not tell `os.stat` how (where) to access these files. You can for instance add:

```
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, root, f)
```

and then use `fullpath` for `stat` or any other operation on those files.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I think you has good mention here ;) Happy coding :)